# Can one make the hand formation of a kohen?

Tags: kohen-priest

Can one make the hand formation of a kohen if they are a yisrael? In addition,can even a kohen make that formation when he isn't blessing the congregation for no reason  (excluding practice)? The reason I ask is because I have heard ppl say one cannot make the hand formation, but there seems to be no source in the Rambam or Shulchan Aruch for it.